# Prolog - Matrix N by N with elements being [1,...,N^2]

Tags: prolog

I'm doing an essay for college. We just started using Prolog so I'm new to it.
I made an auxiliary function that receives a matrix N by N with each row being `[1,2,...N]` so if the matrix is 2 by 2 it would be:

```
[1,2]
[1,2]
```

What I want is the matrix to have every element from `1` to `N^2` so I thought of a way to get it:
To each element of a row, add `(row-1)*N`, that way I would have the matrix like this:
`[1,2][3,4]` or like this: `[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]` if it was a 3 by 3.

Now, to do it I implemented this code:

```
transformamatriz(0,_,_,[]).
transformamatriz(s(F),Iteracion,S1,[L|SQ]) :-
    sumaenfila(S1,L,L),
    mult(s(F),s(Iteracion),S2),
    transformamatriz(F,s(Iteracion),S2,SQ).
```

`S1` and `S2` being what I have to add to each row every time, `s(F)` being `N` and `Iteracion` would be `row-1`.
So when I call the function I do it like this:

```
transformamatriz(N,0,0,MT).
```

I'm using the classic `mult` function:

```
mult(0,_,0).
mult(s(X),Y,Z) :- suma(W,Y,Z), mult(X,Y,W).
```

And suma (add):

```
suma(0,X,X).
suma(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- suma(X,Y,Z).
```

And '`sumafila`' simply adds `N` to each element of a row:

```
sumaenfila(_,[],[]).
sumaenfila(N,[H|T],[H1|T1]) :-
    suma(N,H,H1),
    sumaenfila(N,T,T1).
```

The problems appears to be related to the use of `mult`, I'm attaching a photo of the debugger. After the 1rsts fails, it enters an infinite loop.

[image]

Important: it has to be implemented with Peano numbers.

This is my first Stack Overflow post, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: you don't need `mult`, just add `N` to each number of a row repeatedly, `N-1` times, using recursion.